How in table-metrics made action deleting selected row?
I made the following class using table-metric specified in docs.
class OrdersInInvoiceWithExpireDate extends Table
{
    /**
     * Calculate the value of the metric.
     *
     * @param  \Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\NovaRequest  $request
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function calculate(NovaRequest $request)
    {
        $invoiceOrders = Order::onlyInvoice()->get();

        $rows = [];
        foreach ($invoiceOrders as $invoiceOrder) {
            $iconClass = '';
            $icon = '';
            $subtitle = '';

            ...

            $rows[] = MetricTableRow::make()
                ->icon($icon)
                ->iconClass($iconClass)
                ->title($invoiceOrder->order_number)
                ->subtitle($subtitle)


                ->actions(function () use($invoiceOrder) {
                    return [
                        MenuItem::make('Edit', '/resources/orders/' . $invoiceOrder->id),
                    ];
                });

        }
        return $rows;
    }

Each row has an "Edit" action that opens the order in edit mode, and this works well. Is there a way to add a "Delete" action directly in the table, where clicking it would prompt a confirmation and, if confirmed, delete the selected row. This would allow deleting the row without opening the order’s page.
ADDED INFO :
I have installed "pavloniym/nova-action-buttons": "^1.1" package
and created a new action with command :
php artisan  nova:action Order/DeleteOrder

which filled with log methods to check if these methods are called :
<?php

namespace App\Nova\Actions\Order;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Laravel\Nova\Actions\Action;
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\ActionFields;
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\Text;
use Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\NovaRequest;

class DeleteOrder extends Action
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, Queueable;

    /**
     * Perform the action on the given models.
     *
     * @param  \Laravel\Nova\Fields\ActionFields  $fields
     * @param  \Illuminate\Support\Collection  $models
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(ActionFields $fields, Collection $models)
    {
        \Log::info(varDump($fields, ' -1 handle $fields::'));
        \Log::info(varDump($models, ' -1 handle models::'));
    }

    /**
     * Get the fields available on the action.
     *
     * @param  \Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\NovaRequest  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function fields(NovaRequest $request)
    {
        \Log::info(varDump(-999, ' -999 fields models::'));
        return [
            Text::make(__('Note')),
        ];
    }
}

and in OrdersInInvoiceWithExpireDate table added this action :
    ->actions(function () use($invoiceOrder) {
        return [
            MenuItem::make('Edit', '/resources/orders/' . $invoiceOrder->id),

            ActionButton::make('Delete')
                ->action(new DeleteOrder(), $invoiceOrder->id),

        ];
    });

and on Dashboard page in metrix rows there is one more option 'Delete'
metrics - but clicking on it Dashboard page is just reloaded - I do not see action dialog with
'Note' text input and in log file I have several log lines from fields method.
PS. In description of pavloniym/nova-action-buttons package there are no mentioned that it can be used
with Table Metrics but only on resource table view. Maybe there are some other elements I
can use under Dashboard for pavloniym/nova-action-buttons package?

Looking at table-metric docs, the actions can only be menu-items. Unfortunately, the Action Button will not work in this. You probably need to create a custom tool or resource tool

Could you please provide links to example with  custom tool or resource tool like that ?
